# SSRS: How to add All option to SSRS dropdown filter?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SQL Server Reporting Services for SQL 2008 R2. My reports are filtered by two drop-down menus that are populated from a table, one of them displays a build number. I'd like to give users the option to choose "All" and so return data for all build numbers and not just one.
How do I add this option to my drop-down filter and make it work correctly?
Thanks very much for any help provided.
J.

Comment: Take a look into this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917261/optional-multi-valued-parameters-in-ssrs/12931993#12931993

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I allow a drop-down list parameter in SSRS to have a default value of "-- All -- "?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328712/how-do-i-allow-a-drop-down-list-parameter-in-ssrs-to-have-a-default-value-of)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to use a **multi-value parameter** here, you only want users to run against all builds or just one, not a selection of builds. Otherwise you'd just use a standard **multi-value parameter**.

One way to do this is to return an extra row for all builds in your parameter dataset, e.g. something like:

```
select buildId as null, build = 'All'
union all
select buildId = build, build
from builds
```

I'm returning two columns here so we can pass a NULL value parameter but still have a user-friendly description to display in the report.

Set this up as your parameter dataset. In the report code you can then use the parameter to do something like:

```
select *
from builds
where (@build is null or @build = build)
```

Which will return all builds when `@build` is null and a specified build if `@build` is not null.

Comment: Thanks Ian. After thinking about it, the multi-value parameter suits my needs best and is built-in so I'll go with that. Thanks for your help with this. J.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be correct to simply change the where clause in the stored procedure to

```
Where [field] LIKE @variable
```

Then in SSRS under the Available Values have the "ALL" parameter value be %  (the percent symbol) ?

Is there an error in logic here. It seems to have the desired result

Comment: That'll only work for string fields, which might be fine depending on your usage.