# SSRS string in parameter to change query

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where the WHERE clause is determined by a parameter @param.

`SELECT SOMESTUFF
FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE thing = @param`

I've added values to the parameter so at runtime, the user decides what to run the report for from a drop down box. I want to make an option to run it for all the values I defined as well. I haven't been able to figure out the code to make this happen.

So if I've given values `A, B, C` to the parameter, how do I tell it to do all of them in the expression?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893789/ssrs-how-to-add-all-option-to-ssrs-dropdown-filter/

Comment: @IanPreston I did read that and I am doing a multi value parameter. I'm specifically trying to see how to pass sql from the expression using a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the nature of the query, datatypes etc.

Assuming the 'thing' in your example is a int and your parameters are a comma separated list of int values you could use an IN clause in your query.

SELECT SOMESTUFF FROM SOMETABLE WHERE thing IN (@param)

Though in reality this would need to be an expression in SSRS

="SELECT SOMESTUFF FROM SOMETABLE WHERE THING IN (" + @param.Value + ")"

Seems from your example they may be strings (A,B,C) in which case you would need to put a single quote around each for this to work.

Comment: The thing is text. I'm trying to basically run a query in my report to look for laptops, desktops, servers for an inventory report. I was hoping to use the parameter to change the where clause in my dataset to be either one of those or all of them. I was thinking of making the parameter looks like
'Desktops' OR thing='Laptops' OR thing = 'Servers'

but that doesnt work.