# SQL Single Value or All

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

For report purposes in SSRS I need an SQL query for one parameter which will select only one value or all values (not two or more). It's a single value parameter.

Well, my query should looks like this, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT ft.id, ft.name
FROM fundtable ft
UNION ALL
SELECT '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','All'

DECLARE @funds NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @funds = COALESCE(CAST(entity_id AS NVARCHAR(255)),',')
FROM epev_conduit

SELECT @funds
```

Comment: not quiet sure what you're asking here. can you elaborate.

Comment: i have one table with 6 fund names, and when I want to do report, i want report for one fund and that's easy, it's simple query, but I need to have option to chose all funds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS: How to add All option to SSRS dropdown filter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893789/ssrs-how-to-add-all-option-to-ssrs-dropdown-filter)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this query for a dataset that your parameter is using for the **Available Values**, you don't need to put in into a string. Just use:

```
select ft.id, ft.name    
from fundtable ft
union all    
Select '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','All'
```

The use your **Name** field for the **Label** and your **ID** for the **Value**. You can Specify a Default value expression of

```
="11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"
```

if you want the **default** to be **all**.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.YourTable
WHERE  @id = id 
       OR @id = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
```