# SSRS - Show "select all" text for multi value parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I know how to show all values chosen for a multi value parameter but how do I display just "All" when a user clicks on the "Select All" checkbox? My parameter has a lot of values in it and I don't want them populating in my report which pushes the tablix far down.

Using Report Builder 3.0 here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS Multi Value Parameter. Check whether "Select All" is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095807/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-check-whether-select-all-is-selected)

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried using the following:

Comment: did you got solution for this problem ??

Comment: Don't know what happened with my last post. Can't hit enter for new line in the comments section? Still new here. I tried using the following code: =IIF(COUNTROWS("dtsMain").Equals(Parameters!Department.Count),"ALL Depts",JOIN(Parameters!Department.Label, ", "))  I ran the report and clicked on the "Select All' checkbox. I still get ALL the departments returned instead of just the words "ALL Depts". Just want to avoid every department value taking up a chunk of my report. Thanks.