# Get Count of Shared DataSet when defined with a Parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I commonly display the number of rows of my datasets in SSRS e.g.

```
=CountRows("MyDataSet")
```

However this doesn't work when the dataset is a shared dataset with a parameter.

```
=CountRows("MySharedDatasetWithParameter")
```

Instead it throws an error:

> The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox25.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: (processing): (null != aggregateObj)

How can I get the number of rows in this case?

The dataset "MySharedDatasetWithParameter" does work in normal circumstances, because I am using it to provide the available values to another parameter.

Example of shared dataset with parameter

```
select [Name], [Value]
from dbo.MyList
where MasterList = @MasterList
```

Comment: I would be grateful for the reasons for the downvotes. This is a clear technical issue, very useful (to me at least) and I have spent a large amount of time researching a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9434451/1127428) (Its not a duplicate question else I would flag it as such) is to create a hidden, multi-valued, parameter e.g. `MyHiddenDataSetValues` which stores the values from "MySharedDatasetWithParameter" and then

```
=Parameters!MyHiddenDataSetValues.Count
```

gives the number of rows.

Rather clunky, so still hoping for a way to use `CountRows`.