# Expression to display for the multi value filter parameters on an SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am trying this expression but when I select select all its still giving me only the first employee name. and If I select single employee it is working fine. If I select all the employees in filter I should get the header as All emps. Any work arounds for this?

="Employee Details: " & Parameters!EmpNameNum.Label(0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it might perhaps be better to return "All" with your result set and/or add an expression. Here is an example that may be similar to what you need: [SSRS Multi Value Parameter. Check whether "Select All" is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095807/ssrs-multi-value-parameter-check-whether-select-all-is-selected)

[How do I allow a drop-down list parameter in SSRS to have a default value of "-- All -- "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328712/how-do-i-allow-a-drop-down-list-parameter-in-ssrs-to-have-a-default-value-of)

Comment: Hi Johnny but that link you provided isn't working. All those are giving me just True or False which doesn't really work.

Comment: From doing this a few years ago I recall I may have handled this on the database side, returning "All" and setting the mutli to single value. I have added another link.